# Grouping positive & negative reviews and counting the words

Tags: python, csv

Can somebody help me make the code below smarter and free of redundancy? The code does exactly what I want, but I believe there are many redundant loops and arrays.

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
import re

with open("/Users/max/train.csv", 'r') as file:
  reviews = list(csv.reader(file))

def get_texts(reviews, score):
  texts = [] 
  texts.append([r[0].lower() for r in reviews if r[1] == str(score)]) ; 
  return texts

def getWordListAndCounts(text):
  words = []  
  for t in text:
      for tt in t:
        for ttt in (re.split("\s+", str(tt))):
            words.append(str(ttt))
  return Counter(words)

negative_text_list = get_texts(reviews, -1)
positive_text_list = get_texts(reviews, 1)

negative_wordlist_counts = getWordListAndCounts(negative_text_list)

positive_wordlist_counts = getWordListAndCounts(positive_text_list)

print("Negative text sample: {0}".format(negative_text_list))
print("Negative word counts: {0}".format(negative_wordlist_counts))
print("Positive text sample: {0}".format(positive_text_list))
print("Positive word counts: {0}".format(positive_wordlist_counts))
```

Sample contents in train.csv are as below.

```
i like google,1
google is evil,-1
Apple is cute,1
Microsoft booo,-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually really good.
But:

- `getWordListAndCounts` should be `get_word_list_and_counts`.
  This is as Python has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- You use a `;` but for no reason. It's best to *never* use it.
- In `get_texts` you do `[].append([...])`. This can be: `[[...]]`.
- In `get_texts` you have `r`, it would be better to use `review`,
  this makes it easier to read. Also all the `t`s in `getWordListAndCounts`.
- You can make `getWordListAndCounts` a list/generator comprehension.
- You seem to mix spaces and tabs. This leads to highly breakable code.
  (Look at your question)
- Don't have white space after code. It's really annoying, and violates PEP8.

Overall I would say your code is pretty decent.

I would re-write `getWordListAndCounts` to this for example:

```
def get_word_list_and_counts(text):
    # Rename the `t`'s I have no context on what they are.
    return Counter(
        str(ttt)
        for t in text
        for tt in t
        for ttt in (re.split("\s+", str(tt)))
    )
```

To remove the `[].append`, you can use the following if it has to be a list.

```
def get_texts(reviews, score):
    return [r[0].lower() for r in reviews if r[1] == str(score)]
```

---

As no-one has said it:

`[[...]]` in `get_texts` seems redundent, adds complexity, and makes the algorithm worse in memory, from \$O(1)\$ with generator comprehensions, to \$O(n)\$.

The way you call the code shows us also that there is potential to reduce the complexity.

```
getWordListAndCounts(get_texts(reviews, 1))
```

To show the change to get \$O(1)\$:

```
def get_texts(reviews, score):
    return (
        review[0].lower()
        for review in reviews
        if review[1] == str(score) # use ferada's change
    )

def get_word_list_and_counts(text):
    return Counter(
        word
        for line in text
        for word in (re.split("\s+", line))
    )
```

The above shows you can clearly see it's capable to be in a single function,
if you wish for it.
And remove one of the `for`s in the `get_word_list_and_counts`.

It as one function would look like this:

```
def get_word_list_and_counts(reviews, score):
    return Counter(
        word
        for review in reviews
        if review[1] == str(score)
        for word in re.split("\s+", review[0].lower())
    )
```

That with ferada's change is probably the smallest and most concise you'll get it.
Also the second `for` statement will only run if the `if` is true.

Comment: Thanks Joe, quite helpful. Actually in get_texts, I am trying to avoid getting [[...]] . How can I change  [].append([...]). ? Then I will be able to reduce the number of for loops in getWordListAndCounts.

Comment: @Max `[].append([...])` is the same as `[[...]]`. You can remove the outer `[]`, so that it becomes `[...]`. Or as I put in the answer, `(...)`, if memory is a concern. (Replace `...` with `r[0].lower() for r in reviews if r[1] == str(score)`)

Answer (score 3):

I agree, looks good.  It would really help to have some sample input
btw.

- I can't tell whether either of the `str`s in
  `get_word_list_and_counts` are necessary.  Even with something like
  `get_word_list_and_counts([["hue hue hue"], [1, 2]])` I get a result
  like `Counter({'hue': 3, '2': 1, '1': 1})`, which is the same as if
  the `[1, 2]` was instead `"1 2"`.

The following complaints are mostly micro-optimisations, but it wouldn't
hurt to keep them in mind for future projects.

- `get_texts` is repeatedly calling `str`, that can be avoided by
  storing the string representation or passing in a string in the first
  place.

  ```python
  def get_texts(reviews, score):
      score = str(score)
      return [[r[0].lower() for r in reviews if r[1] == score]]
  ```
- There's no reason not to do the whole process in a loop while reading
  from the CSV file.  That will keep memory consumption down and make
  the program work even on much bigger files.  E.g.:

  ```python
  with open("...") as file:
      for line in csv.reader(file):
          # split line
          # update counter
  ```